# NOT operator on Boolean in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, arduino, logical-operators

I'm trying to use this Arduino code in my program, the LED will stay on
for 5 sec then turns itself off

```
#include <elapsedMillis.h>

int led = 13 ;
elapsedMillis timer0 ;
#define interval 5000
boolean timer0Fired ;

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() 
{
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    timer0Fired = false;
    timer0 = 0; // clear the timer at the end of startup
}

void loop()
{
    if ((!timer0Fired) && (timer0 > interval))
    {
        timer0Fired = true;      // don't execute this again
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);  // turn led off after 5 sec
    }
}
```

I don't understand how the if statement works inside the loop, !timer0Fired should evaluates to 1 but when I print it out it's 0, so when timer0 exceeds the 
interval the if statement should evaluates to be false, I tried it on a UNO and it works.

Comment: You are probably printing it wrong. How are you printing it?

Comment: Is `setup()` ever being called to initialize `timer0Fired`? If not initialized, it will have a garbage value from random memory, so `!timer0Fired` will evaluate to `0` if it has any non-zero value.

Comment: **timer0Fired** is not initialized, is it?

Comment: Can you post an MCVE?

Comment: @ichramm: Global and static variables are zero-initialized by default.

Answer (score 0):

> !timer0Fired should evaluates to 1 but when I print it out it's
>   0

When you print it, do you print "!timer0Fired" or "timer0Fired"? It would explain the output.

> so when timer0 exceeds the interval the if statement should evaluates
>   to be false

Currently, "(timer0 > interval)" evaluates to true when timer0 exceeds the interval, not the contrary. Isn't it correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a basic programming logic.

Imagine that you want to count to 5 and call some function, e.g. `DoSomething`, in and endless loop.

```
int count = 0;
bool called = false; // DoSomething not called yet

while (true) // main loop
{
    ++count;

    if (count == 5)
    {
        // the count is 5
        if (called == false)
        {
            // function not called yet, call it!
            called = true;
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

This might seem as a non-sense in a way. Just wait for it...

However, the problem you're facing is that you don't have a simple counter like mine `count`. Instead, you're using a timer that could be a few milliseconds off and you still want the code to execute even if it's late.

For example:

```
int count = 0;
bool called = false; // DoSomething not called yet

while (true) // main loop
{
    count += 2; // emulate counter being late

    if (count >= 5) // note that count == 5 will be always false here...
    {
        // the count is 5 or more
        if (called == false)
        {
            // function not called yet, call it!
            called = true;
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Now that completely inverses the value of the `if`s. This way, the application almost always passes the first `if` but only **once** the second. In order to optimize this, you can just swap the `if`s:

```
if (called == false)
{
    if (count >= 5)
    {
        called = true;
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

And now, as you probably know, these nested `if` statements can be easily grouped into one using `&&` operator. Also, `called == false` can be made less verbose by using `!called`. This in the end results in

```
while (true) // main loop
{
    count += 2; // emulate counter being late

    if (!called && count >= 5)
    {
        // function not called yet and count is already 5 or more
        called = true;
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

So what is going on is:
a) you want to execute a piece of code only **once**
   - represented by `bool called = false; if (!called) called = true;` logic or `timer0fired` in your code for the matter

b) you want to delay the call until some timer reaches a certain amount
   - represented by `count >= 5` or `timer >= interval` in your example

**tl;dr

Your code is working correctly.**

Comment: Thanks Alegnem, you couldn't have explained more clearly